# What does ⩔ mean?

Tags: logic, notation, terminology

It is probably not a very important question, but it got me very curious.

I found this symbol - $⩔$ in the list of unicode symbols and it states that it is "Double Logical Or".

What does it even mean? Shouldn't the result of the disjunction be the same as the double disjunction?

[A screenshot of the question for those who can't see the symbol on their device.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqoU2.jpg)

Comment: I just see an empty block.

Comment: In computing it might be a logical or operator acting on double-length values.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I've added a screenshot.

Comment: @Shaun: And you included it as a link as opposed to an embedded image because it's your first day using the site? :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila No, it's because it looks ghastly if I use the image! I can't edit the picture itself on my phone, anyway, and I don't have a computer handy, so . . .

Comment: Well, it's a part of the "supplemental mathematical operators" Unicode block. The official Unicode documentation says that this block "contains many additional symbols to supplement the collection of mathematical operators", which I hope is a satisfactory answer to your question.

Comment: To the OP, symbols are generally given within a context. The symbol $e$ could mean the constant $e$, the neutral element of a group, or a function in some contexts. Asking "what does this symbol mean" without providing a context from which the meaning is derived is a meaningless question. You might as well ask what is the meaning of the word "left", right?

Comment: The "supplemental mathematical operators" block, by the way, contains a LOT of stuff that I've never seen before. At least a dozen different variants on the $\geq$ symbol which I suppose someone somewhere must have once used to represent some kind of order relation. I'm guessing this is an issue of a committee not wanting to leave anything out.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I don't think MSE is the right forum for the teleology of Unicode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39313/double-nested-logical-and-and-logical-or-symbols) is realistic, then it can be interpreted as a bitwise-OR operator:

[image]

Comment: Anything can be interpreted as a bitwise-OR operator if one desires so. Let $\aleph$ denote the bitwise-OR operator, then $0\mathbin{\aleph}1=1$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila If you can find something more authoritative, have at it. But at least I found an example. It took me a while to find this one.

Comment: Your answer makes it seem like this is somehow standard. That's my point.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I disagree. "*If* the example ... is realistic, then it *can be* interpreted ..." That's not a strong assertion at all.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Hey, at least it is an example of the actual usage of this symbol!

Answer (score -2):

In the language "R" the operators “|” and “&” indicate the logical operations OR and AND, but the longer form evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each vector. Source: "[Logical operators in R](https://csgillespie.wordpress.com/2010/12/14/logical-operators-in-r/)".

In the language JavaScript [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_OR) (“|” and “&”) treat their operands as a sequence of 32 bits (zeroes and ones), rather than as decimal, hexadecimal, or octal numbers. However, the [logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) ("||" and "&&") actually return the value of one of the specified operands, so if these operators are used with non-Boolean values, they may return a non-Boolean value.

In MathJax \vee $\vee$, \wedge $\wedge$, \bigvee $\bigvee$, \bigwedge $\bigwedge$, \curlyvee $\curlyvee$, **and** \curlywedge $\curlywedge$ **are different** from \lor $\lor$ ***and*** \land $\land$ ***or*** \unicode{x2A54} $\unicode{x2A54}$ **and** \unicode{x2A53} $\unicode{x2A53}$.

[How can I use MathJax / TEX to format bitwise operations?](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/812/how-can-i-use-mathjax-tex-to-format-bitwise-operations).

Proof-Wiki: [Symbols:Logical Operators](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Symbols:Logical_Operators).

"[Fonts and Special Characters for Websites](https://yellowbearjourneys.com/unicode/unicode_arrows.html)".

Comment: Is someone chasing you that you had to post an incomplete answer? You already lost the "first answer" needed for Enlightened badge. So what's the point?

Comment: How is this an answer to the question? The question is what the ⩔symbol is used for in practice, not a question about how to write logical/bitwise operators.

Comment: The first 2 paragraphs explain 2 example usages, the third paragraph gives the MathJax for similar characters **and** the one in question; which in one comment Asaf said there was only an empty block, causing Daniel to include an image instead of relying on MathJax - it is an addition which aids those two and those that arrive here hoping for related information or how to write the symbols. We would benefit from your answer over a comment.